# Is it possible to back fill Google Analytics data to Google BigQuery (where it includes full visitor ID)?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

We had an issue where we lost our connection between Google Analytics and BigQuery for around a month.  After reestablishing the connection, we noticed that the missing data did not back fill and were wondering if there was a way to get that data.  We specifically need data that includes the full visitor ID since we are doing our analysis on the user level.  If anyone can help, it would be greatly be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The big query export from google analytics GA4 does not include historical data.  The data is extracted from the day you configure it on ward.